# need an ebj ear sample file

Tags: weblogic, ejb

Iam in need of an ebj enterprise archive file to test in my weblogic server.

is there any sample open source application?
I googled and downloaded some. but nothing works. can any one help me???

Thanks,
Krishna.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an example project with code here if you are interested:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/samplecode/index.html